# Apache-Mina FTPServer Issue -- Authentication Failed but used correct user/pass...? [Resolved]

Tags: windows, authentication, ftp

I finally got the Mina FTPServer up and running with the help of [Femi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691688/femi) (another user here).

so here's the issue:

I have the server setup for SQL based user management through db-user-manager on my Win2k3 server, and have two users set up in the table:

`john // password`
`jim // password`

Both of them are set to the following table properties:

```
userid      userpassword        homedirectory       enableflag      writepermission     idletime        uploadrate      downloadrate        maxloginnumber      maxloginperip
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john        password            c:\pub\john         1               0                   30              1               NULL                5                   3
jim         password            c:\pub\jim          1               0                   30              1               NULL                5                   3
```

And when logging in to the FTP server using the CORRECT user//password combo of john//password, the log shows this:

```
RECEIVED: USER john
SELECT userid, userpassword, homedirectory, enableflag, writepermission, idletime, uploadrate, downloadrate, maxloginnumber, maxloginperip FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid = 'john'
RECEIVED: PASS *****
SELECT userpassword FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid = 'john'
USER FAILED TO LOG IN
Login Failure - john
SENT: 331 user name okay, need password for john.
SENT: 530 authentication failed.
CLOSED
```

I KNOW for a fact that I didn't screw up entering the username or password (because they are too easy to screw up...), and the fact that I get prompted for the username and password tells me that the host I entered is correct... so where else could I be screwing up at...?

Here is a link to my original post that Femi helped me out in. it contains the xml config file if needed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711542/apache-mina-ftpserver-database-user-manager-failure

Can someone PLEASE help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that in your xml code, for the user manager tag you only have

`<db-user-manager>`

in the documentation, it shows it as

`<db-user-manager encrypt-passwords="salted">`

I think this is where your problem lies. since the encryption isn't defined in your code, it defaults as MD5. change yours to one of the 3 below:

`"Salted"`

`"MD5"`

`"Clear"`

and you should be all set to go. Let me know if it works. The documentation is retarded and says "not required", but I call BS, since it automatically defaults to md5 if left out... so in a way it IS required if you're not using MD5 encryption on your passwords.